# React/redux: In which lifecycle methods is it allowed/forbidden/frowned upon/encouraged to dispatch actions? Why?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In which of the react lifecylcle methods (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) is it allowed/forbidden/recommended/not recommended to dispatch redux actions? Why?

Say my stateless component uses data loaded from the server, is it ok to dispatch an action during `render()` to schedule an ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is opinionated, but it's frowned upon in general: lifecycle methods get called in reaction to a state change up the component tree, but dispatching an action will *probably* initiate another state change. It's the event-handler cascading update situation that redux tries to avoid: you should make state changes in response to actions and nothing else or else you'll have these reactive loops. The state change happens all at once.

In practice this rule gets relaxed for convenience sake pretty often. So there's no real right answer! Like most things in software dev it's nuanced.

Other answer is right about not doing that (or anything impure) in render though: the event you want is probably "when this component is being mounted" vs "whenever its render gets called" which is better handled by `constructor` or `componentWillMount`. Also, anything you'd want to have done in render is better served by `componentDidMount`/`componentWillUpdate`/`componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it seems not clear to me either, why should the `didComponentMount()` care about what `render()` uses (in the case of loading stuff from server). I mean, this leads to logic duplication, whenever I change `render()` I need to change `didComponentMount()`, need to make sure that the two are consistent. This is a source of bugs. I don't see what I gain by putting the ajax calls into `didComponentMount()` , maybe the possibility to course grain (batch) the ajax requests to the server ? Yeah. Not trivial at all.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't dispatch an action in the `render()` method. The following is a quote from the react documentation:

> The `render()` function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser. If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in `componentDidMount()` or the other lifecycle methods instead. Keeping`render()` pure makes components easier to think about.

When you need to fetch data from a server, it is best to do it after the component has mounted, i.e in the `componentDidMount()` method. The react documentation states:

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

If the data from the server depends on some of the `props` or `state` of the component, you would also want to implement the `componentWillReceiveProps()` or `componentWillUpdate()` functions to fetch new data.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about firing an ajax call via an action, you should use `componentDidMount`, which is explicitly recommended by facebook, which says`If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.`

This is because it is possible that rendering a component can take more time than getting a response from the server, then the ajax callback was triggering render on an unmounted component. This is an edge case, and has only happened to me once since I've been developing with React, but nevertheless you should fire ajax calls in `componentDidMount` to be safe.

If your redux action is just making a change to the store, then you can dispatch it whenever you want.

Comment: "This is because it is possible that rendering a component can take more time than getting a response from the server, then the ajax callback was triggering render on an unmounted component. " - this is interesting, what do you mean by rendering a component can take more time ? running `ReactDOM.render()`  ?  so you say that `ReactDOM.render()` finishes later than the ajax call returns? but isn't `ReactDOM.render()` synchronus / blocking ? so that any ajax call's return  `ReactDOM.render()` cannot actually be run before `ReactDOM.render()` returns?  I am confused. Could you please explain ?

Comment: My understanding is that if AJAX calls finish before render() then it will not populate (initial) state, moreover, an asynchronous `setState` on an unmounted component will neither populate the initial state nor cause a re-render, which is why AJAX in `componentWillMount` is discouraged. But I'm not sure 100%.

Comment: Ok, interesting, I cannot really imagine how this can happen, but perhaps I don't get something.